# PHP-SQL : What is the solution if you want to do a search and use UNION with two tables that have differents columns?

Tags: php, mysql

PHP-SQL : What is the solution if you want to do a search (with match and against) and use UNION with two tables that have differents columns (numbers, types, names) because if you use UNION, the columns have to have same name, number and type?
All I found was to use NULL and ALIAS to simulate the columns correponding.
Is there another solution for this case ?

Comment: no. a union creates a "virtual" table from the individual queries. you cannot have the type of a column in that virtual table change half-way through. e.g. `select numberfield ... union select stringfield...`. the DB will use whatever the first query returned for type informtionat, and force the other queries to that type, of possible. if column counts differ, then the "small" column count queries must include hard-coded values to "fill in" the missing columns.

Comment: Lol, I posted exactly that as an answer and had to delete it. No, that's the only answer, unless you use empty string with an alias, or 0 with an alias, or whatever other value you might want depending on the column type expected.